# Localhost still exist after deleting xampp

Tags: localhost, xampp

After installing xampp, somehow localhost bugged on me.

I put my files, changed permissions, in the end deleted the xampp, but I always get this message:

> It works!
>
> This is the default web page for this server.
>
> The web server software is running but no content has been added, yet.

Wiped the folder, tried restarting either, there's no xampp but I'm still getting it, what's the problem?

Comment: Did you clean up your browser browsing settings and cookies , offline ?

Comment: did it just now, didn't help

Comment: in synaptic , you can delete all part of apache

Answer (score 1):

You probably installed a webserver using the Software Centre. Therefore, even if XAMPP is removed, the webserver in Ubuntu still exists and is running.

To figure out which webserver is running (could be Apache2 or Lighttpd or something else), run

```
sudo lsof -i
```

It should output something like (this is shortened view):

```
COMMAND    PID   USER   FD   TYPE  DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
avahi-dae  923  avahi   13u  IPv4    9262      0t0  UDP *:mdns 
avahi-dae  923  avahi   14u  IPv6    9263      0t0  UDP *:mdns 
..............................................................
```

What you are interested in, is the ro that has ***:www** under the *NAME* column.

Once you find the line, then see what it says in the COMMAND column. 
You can then remove the package using the Software Centre.

Comment: It says: gksudo: option requires an argument -- 'i'

Comment: @RnD Try using `sudo` instead of `gksudo`. This isn't a graphical program so there shouldn't be trouble. To user4124, you may want to grep that with `sudo lsof -i|grep "www"`.

Comment: Thanks, I replaced gksudo to sudo. gksudo is weird and barfs on the parameters. For the pedantic, the correct was `gksudo -- lsof -i`

Comment: I just updated the command so that you can now run `lsof`.